# Parsing optional nested XML Elements via JAXB

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I have XML input that could basically look like this:

```
<mxGraphModel>
<root>
<mxCell id="0"/>
<mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
<object label="" Property1="43" id="2">
  <mxCell style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
    <mxGeometry x="196" y="161" width="200" height="30" as="geometry"/>
  </mxCell>
</object>
<object label="" Property2="Helloooo" id="3">
  <mxCell style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
    <mxGeometry x="192" y="269" width="200" height="30" as="geometry"/>
  </mxCell>
</object>
<object label="" Property3="23" id="4">
  <mxCell style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
    <mxGeometry x="210" y="383" width="200" height="30" as="geometry"/>
  </mxCell>
</object>
</root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

I'm trying to parse this input via JAXB:

MxGraphModel.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mxGraphModel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MxGraphModel {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "root")

    @XmlElement(name = "object")
    private ArrayList<MxObject> mxObjects;

    @XmlElement(name = "mxCell")
    private ArrayList<MxCell> mxCells;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

MxObject.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MxObject {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String label;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String documentName;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String documentDescription;

    @XmlElement
    private MxCell mxCell;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

MxCell.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MxCell {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String parent;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String style;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String vertex;

    @XmlElement(name = "mxGeometry")
    private MxGeometry geometry;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

DemoController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/xml")
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public void parseXML(@RequestBody MxGraphModel mxGraphModel) {
        //mxGraphModel contains EITHER objects of type MxObject 
        //OR
        //MxCell
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the parsing operation results in an MxGraphModel object that contains either a collection of objects OR a collection of mxCells - but never both. 
It seems to me that the order in which I declare the XmlElements ("object" and "mxCell") is relevant for the parsing result. When I declare mxCell before object, 2 mxCells are being parsed (which is correct), but the object collection remains null. And the other way around. 
Is it possible to have both XmlElements parsed? I don't know whether the issue is related to the fact that an object element could contain an mxCell element itself...

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it seems the problem is related to the root XmlElement.

Comment: This copes with a single collection and not multiple ones. So when I leave that out of the xml input everything is being parsed correctly. I'll just won't implement root as XmlElementWrapper. That should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you post an answer to your own question so your problem is flagged as answered ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Dimpre Jean-Sébastien:

You're totally right, sorry for posting the answer this late. 
The solution is not to use the root ElementWrapper

So instead of using

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "root")
```

I had to create a root XmlElement in MxGraphModel.java:

```
@XmlElement(name = "root")
private MxRoot mxRoot;
```

Furthermore I created a file called MxRoot.java and moved all collections inside it:

MxRoot.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MxRoot {
    @XmlElement(name = "UserObject")
    private ArrayList<MxObject> mxUserObjects;

    @XmlElement(name = "object")
    private ArrayList<MxObject> mxObjects;

    //XmlElement sets the name of the entities
    @XmlElement(name = "mxCell")
    private ArrayList<MxCell> mxCells;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

It seems the @XmlWrapper Annotation expects exactly one collection. It is not meant to wrap around multiple collections (makes sense now that I know it :))

Thanks to all!